# Why can't I use [Space(15)] before a Variable with inline { get; set; }?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

I am structuring my variables, so I can edit them bette in the Unity Inspector. I am trying to use a [Space(15)] in front of a few variables, which have a { get; set; }. Visual Studio won't compile it.

I placed a variable without { get; set;} in front of the other variables and it seems to compile, but it's a pretty ugly solution. Google wasn't that helpful in my search for a fix.

This doesn't work:

```
    [Space(15)]
        [SerializeField]
        private bool baa { get; set; }
```

This does work:

```
    [Space(15)]
        public int foo;
        [SerializeField]
        private bool baa { get; set; }
```

It should compile without an extra variable to put a ";" in the code. The compiler shows me following Error-Code: CS0592.

Comment: And what is the error message?

Comment: Does the definition of `SpaceAttribute` declare `AttributeTargets.Property`? See [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0592) for more info on CS0592.

Comment: because this `[SerializeField]
        private bool baa { get; set; }` is not a field .. it won't even be displayed since properties are not serializable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot serialize a property. The `SerializeField` attribute is for serializing a `field`. Same goes for `Space`, which ads space in the inspector **before** the marked `field`.

Unity does not directly support the serialization of properties in the inspector.

A workaround, although a bit messy, is to declare a separate field for the property you want to serialize.

```
[Space(15)]
[SerializeField]
private bool _baa;

private bool baa { get => _baa; set => _baa = value; }
```

Comment: the question is then .. do you need a private property for accessing a private field? ;)

Comment: No, most likely not :) but i wanted to stay in the scope of the question. Maybe if you'd want additional some logic in the getter or setter. You could also however use a public property if you would want to implement an interface with a property defined.

Comment: I know that, I just wanted to point out that it makes no sense to use a property at all in this case ;) I don't think it would make your answer out of scope if you removed the property and replaced it by a field entirely

Comment: That may be so, but I'll leave it for those that are searching for a way to serialize properties, because I know I have sought long and hard to accomplish it and could not find a satisfying answer.

Comment: well the answer is you can't ;) but ok let's leave it here